# Is it possible to use the findTopN style method name to limit by a variable number with Spring Data/JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know I can write the following to limit my query to the TOP 1 results:

```
Foo findTopByOrderByTimestampDesc();
```

and the following to limit to the TOP 20 results:

```
List<Foo> findTop20ByOrderByTimestampDesc();
```

I can also do the following like this:

```
Page<Foo> findAll(new PageRequest(0, 20, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "timestamp")));
```

Is it possible to use the findTop style method name to accomplish the same thing? Something like:

```
List<Foo> findTopNByNOrderByTimestampDesc(int n);    // this doesn't work
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use `@Query("your query limit :n")` and pass n as a parameter

Comment: Which version of Spring Data JPA are you using ?

Comment: @royalGhost `1.11.10.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
findAllOrderByTimestampDesc(Pageable pageable)
```

And then use it like this:

```
repository.findAllOrderByTimestampDesc(new PageRequest(0, 20));
```

Comment: If I'm going to use a Pageable, then I will just put the Sort in there, no?